# Is there any way to identify enemy vulnerabilities?

Tags: child-of-light

I'm wondering if there's any way to identify what an enemy's vulnerabilities are outside of just trying different abilities until you find it.

Is there any indication in the enemy sprites that tell you what an enemy is vulnerable to? (i.e. Vulnerable to Fire, Light, Lightning, etc).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A first indication is the background, in the first chapter (forest), enemy was weak to fire, inside the giant, there were lava and enemy was weak to ice... It s not bulletproof tought.

Comment: You can often tell from the enemy itself. If it's a tree, then it's obviously weak to fire, but yeah.. it's hard to tell sometimes :(.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pay attention to enemy colors.

1. Red/Orange is weak to Water
2. Green and brown to Fire
3. Black and grey to Light
4. Blue is weak to Lightning

Some discussions  [here](http://steamcommunity.com/app/256290/discussions/0/558754899102451450/) and [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/727958-child-of-light/69158239)